# Nested scrollview take extra space in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I'm working on a form in android which works for creating a feature for my app. But currently I'm using CoordinatorLayout with Nested scrollview. But it gives a blank space at the bottom of my scroll. How to remove this?

**Here is my xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/ash"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/ash"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/ctl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:background="@color/ash"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/layout_layer"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_chatroom"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/profile_img_bg"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_chatroomname"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/img_chatroom"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Chatroom Name"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/large_text" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_chatroomdescription"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_chatroomname"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Chatroom DescriptionChatroom DescriptionChatroomChatroom DescriptionChatroom DescriptionChatroomChatroom DescriptionChatroom DescriptionChatroomChatroom DescriptionChatroom DescriptionChatroom"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/small_text" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:title="Settings"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_layer"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl_create_menu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rl_picture"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Chatroom Type"
                            android:textColor="@color/black" />

                        <RadioGroup
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <RadioButton
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Public"
                                android:theme="@style/MyRadioButton" />

                            <RadioButton
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Private"
                                android:theme="@style/MyRadioButton" />
                        </RadioGroup>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:padding="10dp">


                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/rl_country_res"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:text="Country Wise Restriction"
                                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/small_medium_text" />
                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <View
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:background="@color/deep_ash" />

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/rl_chatroom_capacity"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Chatroom Capacity"
                                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/small_medium" />
                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <View
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                                android:background="@color/ash" />

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/rl_country"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Country"
                                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/small_medium" />
                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <View
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                                android:background="@color/ash" />

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:padding="5dp">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tv_protect_chatroom"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Protect Chatroom"
                                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/small_medium" />

                                <ToggleButton
                                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                                    android:layout_height="18dp"
                                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                    android:background="@drawable/toggle_silector"
                                    android:checked="false"
                                    android:text=""
                                    android:textOff=""
                                    android:textOn="" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_protect_chatroom"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                    android:text="Without code no one can join with you" />
                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:padding="5dp">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/tv_auto_flood_control"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Auto Flood Control"
                                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/small_medium" />

                                <ToggleButton
                                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                                    android:layout_height="18dp"
                                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                    android:background="@drawable/toggle_silector"
                                    android:checked="false"
                                    android:text=""
                                    android:textOff=""
                                    android:textOn="" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_auto_flood_control"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                    android:text="If you enable flood control , User will be kicked automatically from chatroom" />
                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/rl_idle_time"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Maximum Idle Time"
                                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/small_medium" />
                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <Button
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/shape_for_submit_button"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:padding="4dp"
                                android:text="Create Chatroom"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/small_medium" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I've tried several things found on stack-overflow but not working.How can I solve this problem?

Comment: will you post your output here with extra space ??

Comment: sorry brother , theres is an problem uploading the picture  but I'll try again and let you know. but The problem is when I scroll down always there is an extra empty space created at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Change the height to `match_parent`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
```

I add the `background` and you can see the `color` of it .

Comment: Try and see the color of background .